# I have installed beautifulsoup4, but when I try to import bs4 in python shell, I get ModuleNotFound Error

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, pip

I have repeatedly installed and uninstalled `beautifulsoup4`, but no matter what I try to do, when I try to `import bs4` in shell, I get `ModuleNotFoundError`.

I'm on `Windows 10` and using `Python 3.6.4`. I'm new to programming, but am on my third Python book and this is the first time I've run into a big problem trying to import a module, including those I've installed using `pip`.

Comment: (1) `pip --version` to see what version of Python `pip` corresponds to. (2) `pip freeze` to see that it's installed. (3) `python --version` and `python -c 'import bs4'` just in case.

Comment: C:\>pip --version
pip 9.0.3 from c:\users\victor~1\envs\virtual\lib\site-packages (python 3.6)

Comment: C:\>pip freeze
beautifulsoup4==4.6.0

Comment: C:\>python --version
Python 3.6.4

Comment: C:\>python -c 'import bs4'
  File "<string>", line 1
    'import
          ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Answer (score 1):

Are you writing-

`pip install beautifulsoup4` ?

This will install only `beautifulsoup4` module and not `bs4`.

Do this:-

`pip install bs4`

And then do this in your python file:-

`from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`

Also you may need administrator access for installing.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Yes, I wrote that, but I had also installed bs4 and written "from bs4 import beautifulsoup4", but I still get exactly the same error.

Comment: C:\Users\Victor Hart>pip install bs4
Requirement already satisfied: bs4 in c:\users\victor~1\envs\virtual\lib\site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4 in c:\users\victor~1\envs\virtual\lib\site-packages (from bs4)
You are using pip version 9.0.3, however version 10.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Comment: try installing via pip3, and check whether the module bs4 is in your project's folder or not. If not then do shift it manually.

Comment: I've done that as well, both bs4 and beautifulsoup4. I get the exact same messages.

Comment: I have improved my answer, do this:- from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

Comment: I had already tried that, I get the same answer. No matter what: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'

Comment: c:\users\victor~1\envs\virtual\lib\site-packages ---- this is not the folder where it should be. Visit this place and you will see two dirs named: dist packages and site  packages, then move your bs4 dir. to dist packages dir.  And then try importing BeautifulShop again.

Answer (score 0):

So, I don't really understand what is happening, but I at least temporarily solved my problem. I have two different "Lib > site-packages" directories in my C: drive, and pip is installing in a different one from what Python is using. So I just copied the BeautifulSoup and bs4 folders and pasted them into the one that Python is using, and now it works.

Python is using this folder: "C:\Users\Victor Hart\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32", while pip is installing bs4 and BeautifulSoup here: "C:\Users\Victor Hart\Envs\virtual", which doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: this is not a solution to the underlying problem, which is that you have pip installed in a virtualenv. You need to use the pip that is part of your installed python (might need to install it if its not present), or use the python in `C:\Users\Victor Hart\Envs\virtual\bin`

Comment: see [the documention on using virtual environments](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html) to understand more